# Some kind of "regions" in TypeScript and VisualStudio(2013)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2013

usually we use "regions" in c#, but we miss that feature in typescript.

Is there some kind of grouping ?

I was reading [this article(stackoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801815/regions-in-typescript) and I was wondering may be something has change until now(better plugins) ?

Ty

Answer (score 2):

If you use VSCode (from version 1.17) you can do it like this:

- TypeScript/JavaScript: `//#region` and `//#endregion` and `//region` and `//endregion`
- C#: `#region` and `#endregion`
- C/C++: `#pragma region` and `#pragma endregion`
- F#: `//#region` and `//#endregion`
- PowerShell: `#region` and `#endregion`
- VB: `#Region` and `#End Region`

More about this on link:
[folding regions](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_17#_folding-regions)